# How do you print a C++11 time_point?

Tags: c++, templates, time, c++11, c++-chrono

I've created a time point, but I have been struggling to print it to the terminal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main(){

    //set time_point to current time
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock,std::chrono::nanoseconds> time_point;
    time_point = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    //print the time
    //...

    return 0;
}
```

The only documentation I can find that prints a time_point is found here:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point

however, I'm not even able to create a time_t based on my time_point(like the example).

```
std::time_t now_c = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(time_point); //does not compile
```

**Error:**

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/chrono: In instantiation of ‘constexpr std::chrono::time_point<_Clock, _Dur>::time_point(const std::chrono::time_point<_Clock, _Dur2>&) [with _Dur2 = std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> >; _Clock = std::chrono::system_clock; _Dur = std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1l, 1000000l> >]’:
time.cpp:13:69:   required from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/chrono:540:32: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1l, 1000000l> >::duration(std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >::duration)’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/chrono:540:32: note: candidates are:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/chrono:247:14: note: template<class _Rep2, class _Period2, class> constexpr std::chrono::duration::duration(const std::chrono::duration<_Rep2, _Period2>&)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/chrono:247:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/chrono:243:46: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, void>’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/chrono:240:23: note: template<class _Rep2, class> constexpr std::chrono::duration::duration(const _Rep2&)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/chrono:240:23: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/chrono:236:27: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, void>’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/chrono:234:12: note: constexpr std::chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>::duration(const std::chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>&) [with _Rep = long int; _Period = std::ratio<1l, 1000000l>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/chrono:234:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >::duration {aka std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> >}’ to ‘const std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1l, 1000000l> >&’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/chrono:232:12: note: constexpr std::chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>::duration() [with _Rep = long int; _Period = std::ratio<1l, 1000000l>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/chrono:232:12: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

Comment: I believe `libstdc++` (that is, the GCC implementation of the STL) does not support `std::put_time` yet and then, the example in cppreference doesn't compile. See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html

Comment: By the way, the example on cppreference compiles if you click 'Run this code' and then change the compiler to `clang 3.4 (C++11)`

Answer (score 61, accepted):

(In this post I will omit `std::chrono::` qualifications for clarity. I trust you know where they go.)

The reason your code example fails to compile is that there is a mismatch between the return type of `system_clock::now()` and the type of variable you are trying to assign this to (`time_point<system_clock, nanoseconds>`).

The documented return value of `system_clock::now()` is `system_clock::time_point`, which is a typedef for `time_point<system_clock, system_clock::duration>`. `system_clock::duration` is implementation-defined, with `microseconds` and `nanoseconds` being commonly used. It seems that your implementation uses `microseconds`, so the return type of `system_clock::now()` is `time_point<system_clock, microseconds>`.

`time_point`s with different durations are not implicitly convertible to one another, so you get a compiler error.

You can *explicitly* convert time points with different durations using `time_point_cast`, so the following would compile on your system:

```
time_point<system_clock, nanoseconds> time_point;
time_point = time_point_cast<nanoseconds>(system_clock::now());
```

Notice the explicit template parameter to `time_point_cast` is the target **duration** type, not the target time_point type. The clock types must match in a `time_point_cast`, so specifying the entire time_point type (which is templated on both the clock type and the duration type) would be redundant.

Of course in your case, since you are just looking to print the time point, there is no need for it to be at any specific resolution, so you can just declare `time_point` to be the same type as what `system_clock::now()` returns to begin with. A simple way to do that is to use the `system_clock::time_point` typedef:

```
system_clock::time_point time_point;
time_point = system_clock::now();  // no time_point_cast needed
```

Since this is C++11, you can also just use `auto`:

```
auto time_point = system_clock::now();
```

Having solved this compiler error, the conversion to `time_t` works just fine:

```
std::time_t now_c = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(time_point);
```

and you can now use standard methods for displaying `time_t` values, like `std::ctime` or `std::strftime`. (As **Cassio Neri** points out in a comment to your question, the more C++-y `std::put_time` function is not yet supported by GCC).

Comment: +1 For a much more thorough explanation and for mentioning `auto` (really, it's C++, nobody declares a variable and assigns it in the very next line, even without `auto`).

Comment: @HighCommander4: `time_point`'s with different durations **are** implicitly convertible to one another *if* they share the same `Clock` and if the rhs `Duration` is implicitly convertible to the lhs `Duration`.  In this example, if `system_clock::duration` is microseconds or nanoseconds, it *does* implicitly convert to `time_point<system_clock, nanoseconds>` according to [time.point.cons]/p3.

Comment: Took me a second to realize `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` is the same as `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>`

Comment: OK, but ... how do you print a `std::chrono::time_point`?

Answer (score 30):

Updated answer for an old question:

For a `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, some-duration>` there is now a 3rd party libraries that give you much better control.  For time_points based on other clocks, there is still no better solution than to just get the internal representation and print it out.

But for `system_clock`, using [this library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date), this is as easy as:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    std::cout << system_clock::now() << " UTC\n";
}
```

which just output for me:

```
2016-07-19 03:21:01.910626 UTC
```

which is the current UTC date and time to microsecond precision.  If on your platform `system_clock::time_point` has nanosecond precision, it will print out nanosecond precision for you.

### 2021 Update

Here is the C++20 version of the above program:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    std::cout << std::chrono::system_clock::now() << " UTC\n";
}
```

Comment: hmm, this should be in the standard imo.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal:  Working on it (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0355r1.html).  This will very likely need **your** very vocal help.  Significant forces on the committee do not like this proposal and will win out if the public does not shout them down.

Comment: Competing proposals with alternative (imho inferior) design.  Look for revision 3 of my proposal to appear within about a week at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/

Comment: Now that "slightly modified version of" date.h went into C++ 2a, is time_point output part of it? I'm using latest gcc with -std=c++2a and not geting it

Comment: `time_point` output when `time_point` is based on `system_clock` is part of the draft C++2a.  It is a big proposal though and no one I'm aware of has shipped it yet.

Comment: Re the 2021 update, [still not supported as of gcc 11.2](https://godbolt.org/z/1cfn56bzY), I couldn't get clang 14 or msvc 19 to compile it either, hopefully support for that coming soon.

Comment: This now compiles and works with MSVC 19: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5TfvYszME

Comment: Still doesn't work for gcc 12.2 (xtensa fork)

Comment: https://wandbox.org/permlink/eMNkeUQQANLksAwH

Answer (score 20):

This snippet might help you:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

template<typename Clock, typename Duration>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &stream,
  const std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration> &time_point) {
  const time_t time = Clock::to_time_t(time_point);
#if __GNUC__ > 4 || \
    ((__GNUC__ == 4) && __GNUC_MINOR__ > 8 && __GNUC_REVISION__ > 1)
  // Maybe the put_time will be implemented later?
  struct tm tm;
  localtime_r(&time, &tm);
  return stream << std::put_time(&tm, "%c"); // Print standard date&time
#else
  char buffer[26];
  ctime_r(&time, buffer);
  buffer[24] = '\0';  // Removes the newline that is added
  return stream << buffer;
#endif
}

int main() {
  std::cout << std::chrono::system_clock::now() << std::endl;
  // Wed May 22 14:17:03 2013
}
```

Comment: Only `std::chrono::system_clock` supports `to_time_t` so I think it does not make sense to have this as a template. Instead the time_point could be passed directly as `const system_clock::time_point &time_point`.

Comment: Depends if a user creates a user defined clock that has `to_time_t` on it.

Answer (score 13):

The `nanoseconds` seems to be part of the problem, looking at the documentation a bit I was able to get this to work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>


int main(){

    //set time_point to current time
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> time_point;
    time_point = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    std::time_t ttp = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(time_point);
    std::cout << "time: " << std::ctime(&ttp);

    return 0;
}
```

Although it looks like `std::chrono::microseconds` works ok:

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock,std::chrono::microseconds> time_point;
```

Comment: By the way, a much more concise `auto time_point = std::chrono::system_clock::now();` would probably have done, too.

Comment: @ChristianRau Sure, fair point, I usually like to keep the code as close to the original posted code as possible unless it is obviously broken or wrong.

Comment: Also a much much more concise one: `high_resolution_clock::now()`.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone working with `time_point<steady_clock>` (not `time_point<system_clock>`):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

template<std::intmax_t resolution>
std::ostream &operator<<(
    std::ostream &stream,
    const std::chrono::duration<
        std::intmax_t,
        std::ratio<std::intmax_t(1), resolution>
    > &duration)
{
    const std::intmax_t ticks = duration.count();
    stream << (ticks / resolution) << '.';
    std::intmax_t div = resolution;
    std::intmax_t frac = ticks;
    for (;;) {
        frac %= div;
        if (frac == 0) break;
        div /= 10;
        stream << frac / div;
    }
    return stream;
}

template<typename Clock, typename Duration>
std::ostream &operator<<(
    std::ostream &stream,
    const std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration> &timepoint)
{
    Duration ago = timepoint.time_since_epoch();
    return stream << ago;
}

int main(){
    // print time_point
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> now =
        std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << now << "\n";

    // print duration (such as the difference between 2 time_points)
    std::chrono::steady_clock::duration age = now - now;
    std::cout << age << "\n";
}
```

The decimal number formatter is not the most efficient, but needs no beforehand knowledge of the number of decimals, which is not known if you want `resolution` to be templated, unless you can come up with a constant expression for `ceil(log10(resolution))`.

Comment: For extra speed you could use my itoa (which indeed has a constant expression for ceil(log10(resolution), but only to static assert that the passed buffer is large enough ;)... https://github.com/CarloWood/ai-utils/blob/master/itoa.h#L46

Answer (score 1):

The ctime() does not work for Visual C++. I use MS Visual Studio 2013. I changed the above code to use ctime_s(...), as prompted by MSVC compiler. It worked.

```
//set time_point to current time
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> time_point;
time_point = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

std::time_t ttp = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(time_point);
char chr[50];
errno_t e = ctime_s(chr, 50, &ttp);
if (e) std::cout << "Error." << std::endl;
else std::cout << chr << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another snippet of code.
Plus side is that it is fairly standalone and supports microsecond text representation.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const std::chrono::system_clock::time_point& point)
{
    auto time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(point);
    std::tm* tm = std::localtime(&time);
    char buffer[26];
    std::strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.", tm);
    stream << buffer;
    auto duration = point.time_since_epoch();
    auto seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(duration);
    auto remaining = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(duration - seconds);
    // remove microsecond cast line if you would like a higher resolution sub second time representation, then just stream remaining.count()
    auto micro = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(remaining);
    return stream << micro.count();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<chrono>
#include<thread>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;

string getTimeAsStr(chrono::system_clock::time_point& t)
{
    std::time_t time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(t);
    std::string time_str = std::ctime(&time);
    time_str.pop_back();
    return time_str;
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, chrono::system_clock::time_point& t)
{
    os<<getTimeAsStr(t);
    return os;
}
int main()
{
    chrono::system_clock::time_point currentTime = chrono::system_clock::now();
    cout << currentTime<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr How to print a raw `std::chrono::time_point`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
  // begin is a std::chrono::time_point type
  // You can also use ::system_clock::now() to get the time since
  // Jan 1 1970 (differences between these linked below)
  auto begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

  // print as nanoseconds. Can also choose ::microseconds, ::seconds, ::minutes,
  // ::hours. The type returned from .time_since_epoch() is
  // std::chrono::duration
  std::cout << "begin: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(begin.time_since_epoch()).count();

  return 0;
}
```

---

Goodness, what I thought would be a 30 second google search turned into a research project down the rabbit hole.  All I wanted to do print out some raw time points in my program to compare them visually, no interest in pretty print.  I'm sure these other answers work too, but they have a whole lot of code, use ctime `struct`s, 3rd party libraries, etc.  I was looking for a minimal, "print this value as is" solution, and didn't find much that direct.  It seems that you can't simply print a `::time_point`:

```
auto begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
// BAD CODE, none of these work, in C++17 anyway
std::cout << begin;
std::cout << std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(begin);
std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(begin).count();
std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(begin - 0).count();
```

Rather, it appears you can only print a *duration*, so what's illustrated at the top is a quick way of creating a duration (sourced from [here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/time_point/time_since_epoch/)), from `now` until the beginning of the epoch, which differs depending on the clock you use (basically, the [`::system_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock) is the wall clock time, and the [`::steady_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock) is a monotonic clock that begins at some point, such as system power on).  For my purposes, the `::steady_clock` is surely the better choice, but shouldn't matter all that much as long as I'm comparing apples to apples.  I was just looking for some visual feedback, not something super accurate.

I've created a scratchpad [demonstration](https://godbolt.org/z/E5fzf9P1P) here of how to print the time points I was interested in, and some differences between `::steady_clock` and `::system_clock`.