# Can I avoid going through time_t to print a time_point?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, c++-chrono, time-t

Here's an example [adapted from cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>

int main() {
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::time_t now_c = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
    std::cout << "The time was just "
              << std::put_time(std::localtime(&now_c), "%F %T") << '\n';
}
```

I don't like this. I want to print my time point without having to go through `time_t`. Can I do so...:

1. at all?
2. with an arbitrary format like `put_time` supports?

**Notes:**

- Standard library solutions are best; non-standard but robust solutions are also relevant.
- Not a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777073/how-do-you-print-a-c11-time-point) - since I'm also interested in arbitrary format printing; but it should be noted that @HowardHinnant's answer to that one resolves the first part of this one.

Comment: @inf: Seriously, did you read the two questions before marking as a dupe? Now, it's true that one of the _answers_ to that question also answers this one, but you wouldn't know it from reading the question or most of the answers.

Comment: So all good then?

Comment: @inf: No, see my first answer.

Comment: The answer to your questions is that you obviously can't. Otherwise those other answers would be outdated. The other question asks exactly the same question of how to print a time point. As depicted in the answers using time_t is the way to go. You should also read the comments regarding standardisation of a nicer way.

Comment: I reopened this answer.  The previously indicated dupe did not have the "without going through a `time_t` clause, which is significant because the trip through `time_t` looses fractional second information.

Comment: @inf: You (and other close-voters) were too quick to judge my question. More generally, we should not use overly expansive criteria to decide a question is a dupe. If two questions have a partial answer share, that's not enough. Please be more patient with related questions and consider question asker's perception of dupeness more.

Comment: Nope, if you would have read the question & answers of the other questions you would have found Howard's library as well. Also if you are looking for a non-standard solution you should say so.

Comment: @inf: 1. A person looking for an answer to my question is not likely / not likely enough to find the other question + think the answers would address their question + scour everything + follow links to see whether the information there solves their question. There are multiple highly-voted question pairs which meet your criterion for dupeness. 2. About your second point - fair enough, but even if I had said "standard solution only", it is still worthwhile having that part of the question answered by "no solution in the standard library up to C++17".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Howard Hinnant's library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) - which has been voted to become part of C++20 - also supports `put_time`-like formatting.

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    std::cout << date::format("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p\n", std::chrono::system_clock::now());
}
```

Example output:

```
07/22/2018 03:30:35.001865 AM
```

Answer (score 1):

A partial solution which doesn't allow you a choice of printing format or timezone, thanks to @inf's suggestion, is found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38449096/1593077): you can simply pipe a timepoint to the standard output to get a UTC timestamp string for it:

```
std::cout << std::chrono::system_clock::now() << " UTC\n";
```

but the question remains open for arbitrary formats.