# High res timer logging

Tags: c++, logging, high-resolution-time

I'm writing multithreading app on C++ and I need logging with timestamps to workout data races synchronization etc. This means that I need to log time with milliseconds at least. I looked all over the internet to find the way just to print `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point` in a way like `14:08:12.132`

I know that it should be trivial. I will appreciate for the working solution.

Comment: Are you aware of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777073/how-do-you-print-a-c11-time-point)?

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning about multi-threading BTW.

Comment: Seems like an XY problem to me. You are trying to solve a problem 'Y' and then apply the solution to solve 'X'. Nevertheless, I really don't think logs with timestamps are the proper solution to your 'X' problem.

Comment: the multithreading part is to check watchdog thread work and work threads ticking

Comment: @lubgr I saw that topic. But the only explicit answer is to use 3rd party library.