# C++ print chrono::time_point<chrono::high_resolution_clock> to be readable

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I have the number of nanoseconds since Epoch and I'd like to print this to be readable.

The examples I found online printing `time_point` were using `system_clock` and then converting to a `std::time_t`. However, I am using `high_resolution_clock` (because of the nanoseconds), hence struggling to understand how I can print this.

What is the best technique, given I am dealing with nanoseconds? I'd prefer to stick with standard libraries if possible.

I'm stuck with C++17 for now, but please do mention if C++20 makes this much easier to do.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using TimePoint = std::chrono::time_point<Clock>;

int main()
{
    const uint64_t nanosSinceEpoch = 1517812763001883383;
    const Clock::duration duration_ns_since_epoch = std::chrono::nanoseconds(nanosSinceEpoch);

    const TimePoint tp(duration_ns_since_epoch);

    // Would like to print tp in readable format
}
```

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777073/how-do-you-print-a-c11-time-point

Comment: @NathanOliver That example is using system_clock, which causes a compile error creating from chrono::nanoseconds

Comment: @user997112 But the accepted answer ends with conversion to `std::time_t`, which is much more printing friendly, and mentions common ways to print such structure.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I completely agree, i wanted to use that approach but I'm unsure how to create time_t from high_resolution_clock?

Comment: Ah, right, function `to_time_t` only exists in `system_clock`, my bad. Though it seems that using `high_resolution_clock` directly is discouraged (or at least cppreference discourages that).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen to be honest I think the high_resolution_clock might not matter. I just need whatever creates a std::time_t using nanoseconds since epoch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`high_resolution_clock` does not have a portable epoch.  It might be 1970.  It might be whenever your device booted up.  Thus when printing its `time_point`, the best that can be done is to print the underlying duration.

`system_clock` can represent `nanoseconds` even if `system_clock::time_point` does not.  The trick is to use the more generic form of `time_point` which is:

```
template <class Clock, class Duration>
class time_point;
```

You can specify a clock and a duration, for example:

```
time_point<system_clock, nanoseconds> tp;
```

I like to set up a templated type-alias to do this:

```
template <class Duration>
    using sys_time = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, Duration>;
```

And now I can use this simpler syntax:

```
sys_time<nanoseconds> tp;
```

In C++20, `sys_time` is provided for you by `<chrono>`.  And C++20 allows you to simply print out `system_clock`-based `time_point`s.

Unfortunately I don't believe anyone is shipping this part of C++20 yet.  However there's a [header-only, open source, free preview of C++20 `<chrono>`](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) that works with C++11/14/17:

```
#include "date/date.h"

#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const uint64_t nanosSinceEpoch = 1517812763001883383;

    const std::chrono::nanoseconds d(nanosSinceEpoch);
    using date::operator<<;
    std::cout << date::sys_time<std::chrono::nanoseconds>{d} << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
2018-02-05 06:39:23.001883383
```

### Update to address time zones

There is a [second `<chrono>` preview library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) at the same link in the header tz.h which deals with time zones.  This library is not header-only.  There's a single source file associated with it, tz.cpp.  [Here are directions for compiling it.](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation)

This library can be used to translate `sys_time` (aka [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) / UTC) into any [IANA time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

For example if you need to display the above output in "America/Chicago" (even if your computer isn't in Chicago), then it can be done like this:

```
#include "date/tz.h"

#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const uint64_t nanosSinceEpoch = 1517812763001883383;

    using namespace std::chrono;
    date::sys_time<nanoseconds> tp{nanoseconds(nanosSinceEpoch)};
    std::cout << date::zoned_time{"America/Chicago", tp} << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
2018-02-05 00:39:23.001883383 CST
```

This is also part of C++20 `<chrono>`.  `zoned_time` is a pairing of a time zone and a `sys_time`, of any precision as long as it is seconds or finer.  Its streaming operator includes the time zone abbreviation.  There is also a `format` function (`std::format` in C++20, `date::format` in the library) that can be used to customize the output.  For example:

```
date::zoned_time zt{"America/Chicago", tp};
std::cout << date::format("%F %T%z", zt) << '\n';
```

Output:

```
2018-02-05 00:39:23.001883383-0600
```

Comment: Thank you Howard. I will give that a try. And thank you for getting this in to C++20. There's far too many trivial tasks which are 5-10 lines in C++. This is one of them.

Comment: Unfortunately getting compiler error date.h:1066:23: error: 'uncaught_exception' is deprecated. !std::uncaught_exception() &&

Comment: There are two ways to deal with this:  1) Don't convert warnings into errors.  Or 2)  Define `HAS_UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTIONS=1` prior to including date.h.

Comment: Howard, got a question if that's okay? The nanos I have was taken in timezone CET but my machine is in a different timezone. How can I instruct the formatter to use CET?

Comment: There's a way to do that, and I'll update my answer to address it.  But first, can you be more specific about your target time zone?  CET is an abbreviation of several time zones.  Perhaps "Europe/Berlin"?

Comment: Apologies, my source is Chicago time (CPT i think?)

Comment: No problem.  Updated my answer to use "America/Chicago".

Comment: Is there anything different about the time zone header? I get a linker error when I include it. tz.h:896: undefined reference to `date::time_zone::get_info_impl(std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1l> > >) const'

Comment: This means you haven't compiled and linked to tz.cpp.  Here are the instructions for different platforms and options: https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation

Comment: Hi Howard, I've started using the time zone, but got linker errors. I've added add_subdirectory("<path>/cpp20_datelib/") and added date::date to target_link_libraries, but I'm getting "cpp20_datelib/include/date/tz.h:314: undefined reference to `date::locate_zone(std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >)'" Am I integrating this correctly with CMake?

Comment: Sorry, I don't personally use the CMake system that is published with my date library.  It is maintained by other contributors.  For me CMake causes many more problems than it solves for this simple library.  This library contains only 1 source file: tz.cpp.  If you compile that source along with whatever source contains your `main()` function, then it just works.  The installation instructions linked about contain some additional configuration options.